# React Hook Testing Children callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-test-renderer

So a test should provide input for a function and test the output.  With React the input for the function may come from either `props` or the child component/function.  Ok there are other ways too but for now let's look at those two ways.

I have a Container component that does some business logic and renders a child:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import ExampleView from './ExampleView'

const ExampleContainer = ({ onSomeBusinessDone, iHaveMounted }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // An example of a "on mount" style effect that we may need to test
    // Grab data, do some initial logic whatever, but test that I call a prop
    // within this mount call
    iHaveMounted()
  }, [])

  const onDoSomeBussinessLogic = (eventData = {}) => {
    // Do something with the data perhaps
    eventData.whoa = true
    onSomeBusinessDone(eventData)
  }

  return <ExampleView onSomething={onDoSomeBussinessLogic} />
}

export default ExampleContainer
```

That Container provides a callback style `prop` to the child.  The goal is to test that when the child calls this function the Container does something with it and then calls its own callback style prop (aka the output we would want to test).

**The problem I'm having is how do I trigger this function that is provided to the child in Jest/React with hooks?**

The setup is a bit difficult to explain here in words, but I do have a repo and codesandbox:
https://github.com/Kikketer/hooks-test-questions
https://codesandbox.io/embed/hooks-tests-questions-vvrv6

The sandbox one is best for looking but I couldn't figure out how to run jest in there, so it would be easiest to try it out after cloning.

There are a couple things in play here:

1. I can't use a shallow renderer because I also need to validate the `useEffect` hooks call a property as well.
2. I use a mock rendering of the child component in Container function so that it doesn't attempt to render the child since I'm only testing the Container I shouldn't need to worry about dependencies or other failures of that child.  Only that I'm passing in useful and expected props.

My test looks like this:

```
  jest.mock('./ExampleView', () => props => <div data-id="ExampleView" {...props} />)
  ...
  ...

  test('when a child does something expect the prop function to have `whoa`', () => {
    const onSomething = jest.fn()
    act(() => {
      renderer.create(<ExampleContainer onSomething={onSomething} />)
    })
    // Somehow trigger the child's action... not sure how
    // Urm....
    expect(onSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ clicked: true, whoa: true })
  })
```

Again I mock the View because I can't use a shallow renderer and I don't want to render the children.  I just want to validate the props (which a snapshot does nicely).

**How I've done this using class**

Before hooks I would be able to reach into the component and call a function directly:

```
const onSomeBusinessDone = jest.fn()
const iHaveMounted = jest.fn()
const component = new ExampleContainer({onSomeBusinessDone, iHaveMounted})
component.onDoSomeBussinessLogic({clicked: true})
// I can check to see that given the input (clicked) I get the output:
expect(onSomeBusinessDone).toHaveBeenCalledWith({clicked: true, whoa: true})
```

I realize that creating a `new` react component is frowned upon but this would allow me to run this test pretty simply.  I don't believe I would be able to do similar format with Hooks because it's a function that does not expose the inner functions.